# Call method after random interval of time

Tags: c#

I have 5 methods and I need them to be called after random interval(1 to 3 sec) of time. Say first method is called after 1 sec, then second method is called after 2.3 sec, next method after 1.5 etc. I did following using timer

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    fortimerinterval1 = rand.Next(1000, 3000);
    mytimer1.Interval = fortimerinterval1; 
    mytimer1.Enabled = true;
    mytimer1.Start();
```

But the problem is, timer interval do not change everytime. Timer interval remain constant after first time. How to make it random so that each time timer interval change.

Comment: Use a single timer with a fixed interval, say, 100 ms, and call your methods in it using the random function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do something like this

```
Random rand = new Random();
Timer mytimer = new Timer();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mytimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);
    int fortimerinterval = rand.Next(1000, 3000);
    mytimer.Interval = fortimerinterval;
    mytimer.Enabled = true;
    mytimer.Start();
}

public void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
{
    int fortimerinterval = rand.Next(1000, 3000);
    mytimer.Interval = fortimerinterval;

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Set the interval in your timer elapsed method.

```
    Random rand = new Random();

    private void OnTick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {

        _timer.Interval = rand.Next(1000, 3000);
    }
```

Comment: Could you please give me more details? When I use your code, it shows _timer don't exist. Then i used mytimer1 but it don't affect the code.

Answer (score 1):

Watch out for overlapped callbacks if you use System.Timers.Timer.  For example, if the first tick fires after 1 second and the method that you call in the tick callback takes longer than 1 second to complete, you'll end up with another tick callback being called 1 second after the first, before you change the interval.

I would use a System.Threading.Timer configured to fire once and in the callback method change it to fire again at the next random interval.

Like this:

```
    public TestClass()
    {
        _random = new Random(Environment.TickCount);
        _timer = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, _random.Next(1000, 3000), Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    private void TimerCallback(object state)
    {
        try
        {
            // Do something.
        }
        finally
        {
            _timer.Change(_random.Next(1000, 3000), Timeout.Infinite);
        }
    }
```